# Slide Up Footer OnHover and OnClick?

Tags: jquery, onclick, sticky-footer, sliding, onhover

I am looking to modify these two slideup footer examples so that they work on mobile devices. How do I add onClick open and onClick close to these for us on mobile and still have onHover work for desktop use?

The close and open onClick would need to be active on the "Footer Button" text or a set of two images (1 for footer button open, and 1 for footer button close) that would be added later.

http://jsfiddle.net/aQmHB

```
$(".footer").hover(function () {
$(".slide").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a88m6

```
$(".footer").hover(function () {
$(this).animate({height: 250});
}, function(){
$(this).animate({height: 25});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can normally user agent to determine if it is being seen on mobile or desktop, and handle each independently accordingly. So check what the user agent is, then bind events how you would like it to be handled.

Comment: Actually, I think it would be okay if the click and hover were active on desktop and mobile. The hover just won't work on mobile, but it's okay if both work on desktop. If anyone has code examples, let me know. I'm very newby at jquery,